# Let $f(z)$ be entire and $|f(w)-f(z)|\le R|w-z|$ for arbitrary $w, z$ in C and $R>0$. Prove that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

From an old examination paper:

Let $f(z)$ be entire and $|f(w)-f(z)|\leq R|w-z|$ for arbitrary $w, z$ in $\mathbb C$ and $R>0$.  Prove that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree less than 2.

I have absolutely no idea where to start so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite the inequality as

$$
\frac{|f(w) - f(z)|}{|w - z|} \leq R
$$

Then what does this tell you about the derivative of $f$?

Comment: great I didn't even see that thank you!

Comment: @katherinebarry I'm glad that it helped you =)

Answer (score 2):

Since $\dfrac{f(w) - f(0)}{w}$ is a bounded entire function (set $z = 0$, and continue analytically to $w=0$), by Liouville's theorem it's constant.

Comment: (+1): It's *almost* an entire function--it has a removable singularity at $w=0$. You should fix that.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, of course.